# UPS freight calculator

Tags: php, calculator, ups

I have managed to get a UPS Shipping calculator working in PHP.  I now found out that the standard shipping from UPS is capped at 150lbs.  For anything over 150lbs, I need to ship via freight.

Has anyone ever coded a Freight Calculator with UPS?  The calculator I wrote for anything under 150lbs does not require a UPS account.  I was hoping to do the same for the freight calculator, however, I am unable to find any information on how to accomplish this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

As per request by Nicolaesse, I have added some code snippets that I wrote in 2009 to solve my problem.

Demo can be seen here:
http://cart.jgallant.com   (Add product to cart, checkout, and enter zipcode for shipping estimate)

Core UPS class:

```
<?php
    class ups {

    function getMethod() {
        $method= array(
                '1DA'    => 'Next Day Air',
                '2DA'    => '2nd Day Air',
                '3DS'    => '3 Day Select',
                'GND'    => 'Ground',
            );
        return $method;
    }

    function get_item_shipping($weight, $zipcode)
    {
        unset($_SESSION['zipcode_error']);
        if($weight > 150) {
             $_SESSION['zipcode_error'] = "A cart item requires freight.";
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['zipcode_error'])) {
            $services = $this->getMethod();
            $ch = curl_init();
            foreach ($services as $key => $service) {
                $Url = join("&", array("http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi?accept_UPS_license_agreement=yes",
                "10_action=3",
                "13_product=".$key,
                "14_origCountry=US",
                "15_origPostal=90210",
                "19_destPostal=" . $zipcode,
                "22_destCountry=US",
                "23_weight=" . $weight,
                "47_rate_chart=Regular+Daily+Pickup",
                "48_container=00",
                "49_residential=2",
                "billToUPS=no")
                );

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    $Results[]=curl_exec($ch);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            $pre = "";
            $shipping_list = array();
            foreach($Results as $result) {
                $result = explode("%", $result);
                if ($services[$result[1]] != ''){
                    if ((($result[1]=='XPR') && ($pre == 'XPR')) || (($result[1]=='XDM') && ($pre == 'XDM')) || (($result[1]=='1DP') && ($pre == '1DP')) || (($result[1]=='1DM') && ($pre == '1DM')) || (($result[1]=='1DA') && ($pre == '1DA')) || (($result[1]=='2DA') && ($pre == '2DA')))
                        $shipping_list += array($services[$result[1]."L"] => $result[8]);
                    else if (($result[1]=='GND') && ($pre == 'GND'))
                        $shipping_list += array($services[$result[1]."RES"] => $result[8]);
                    else
                        $shipping_list += array($services[$result[1]] => $result[8]);
                    $pre = $result[1];
                }
            }
        }
        $shipping_list = array_reverse($shipping_list);
        return $shipping_list;
    }

}


?>
```

WEIGHT Calculator Helper:

```
<?php

    //UPS calculator - Divides packages into 150lbs max packages, and requests multiple quotes if needed
    //Returns a sum of all the quotes added together.  
    private function calculate_per_item_shipping() {

        $currWeight = 0;
        $packageCount = 0;

        //Loop thru cart items - adding weights to packages
        foreach($this->get_contents() as $item) { 
            for ($i = 0; $i < $item["qty"]; $i++) {
                $itemWeight = $item["weight"];

                if ($itemWeight > 150) {  // A single item cannot be more than 150lbs
                  $_SESSION['zipcode_error'] = $item['name'] . " weighs more than 150lbs.";
                  return false;
                }
                else {
                  $currWeight += $itemWeight;           //Add item weight to active package
                  if ($currWeight > 150)  {             //Max weight reached for active package
                    $currWeight -= $itemWeight;         //Remove item from current package, too heavy
                    $loopPack = 0;                                  
                    $itemUsed = false;

                    //Check if an existing package can take the item
                    while (($loopPack != $packageCount) or ($itemUsed = false)) {
                      if ($packages[$loopPack] + $itemWeight < 150) {
                        $packages[$loopPack] += $itemWeight;
                        $itemUsed = true;
                      }
                      $loopPack++;
                    }

                    //if the item didn't fit in an existing package, create a new package for it
                    if ($itemUsed == false) {
                      $packageCount++;
                      $packages[$packageCount-1] = $currWeight;
                      $currWeight = $item["weight"];        //Put unused item back in active package            
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        //The remainder becomes a package
        $packageCount++;
        $packages[$packageCount-1] = $currWeight;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $packageCount; $i++) {
            $temptotal = $this->calc_package_shipping($packages[$i]);
            if ($temptotal['Ground'] != 0) { $total['Ground'] += $temptotal['Ground']; }
            if ($temptotal['3 Day Select'] != 0) { $total['3 Day Select'] += $temptotal['3 Day Select']; }
            if ($temptotal['2nd Day Air'] != 0) { $total['2nd Day Air'] += $temptotal['2nd Day Air']; }
            if ($temptotal['Next Day Air Saver'] != 0) { $total['Next Day Air Saver'] += $temptotal['Next Day Air Saver']; }
            if ($temptotal['Next Day Air Early AM'] != 0) { $total['Next Day Air Early AM'] += $temptotal['Next Day Air Early AM']; }
            if ($temptotal['Next Day Air'] != 0) { $total['Next Day Air'] += $temptotal['Next Day Air']; }
        }

        $this->selectedQuoteAmount = $total['Ground'];

        return $total;
    }



    private function calc_package_shipping($weight) {
        $ups = new ups();
        $shipping = $ups->get_item_shipping($weight, $this->zipcode);
        return $shipping;
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: is you code, which allow to calculate the rate wihout a UPS account, still working? I am really interesting in it.

Comment: @Nicolaesse Yes it is, as far as I know.  I don't have a "demo" of the code, so you will need to work it out yourself, but I can post it for you.

Comment: @Nicolaesse Posted the code above for you.  Wrote that in 2009, and it still works.  :)

Comment: I would gladly pay for a working sample zip of this UPS calculator @Jon. Is that possible?

Comment: @jon thanks! sending email now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding multiple quotes together - So a shipment that was between 150 lbs - 300 lbs would be split into two packages, and the two rate quotes would be added together to form the total rate cost.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just get a [UPS API account](http://www.ups.com/e_comm_access/gettools_index?loc=en_US) and request up-to-date rates directly from UPS?

Comment: I can't speak for Jon, but I wrote something like this for a job interview prescreen question once.  I don't think I would have gotten the interview if I had made UPS do all the work...

More seriously (to Jon), why can't you just use your existing code and plug in different rates?

Comment: The rate API will allow you to add multiple packages to a shipment

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US you should try to use [this classes](http://code.google.com/p/ups-php/) for the rate and the tracking.
I am sure you will need a UPS API account.